# How does one correctly scale tabu (not tabular)?

Tags: tabu

Can someone explain the (what is to me) weird behavior of `adjustbox` in the second and third cases below?

Why is it that all three cases produce different results?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\centering

With ``c''.
\vspace{1ex}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=7em}
%
\begin{tabu}{c}
  \toprule
  \\
  Some reasonably, very much so, long text.
  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
%
\end{adjustbox}

\vspace{3ex}

With ``X[c]''.
\vspace{1ex}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=7em}
%
\begin{tabu}{X[c]}
  \toprule
  \\
  Some reasonably, very much so, long text.
  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
%
\end{adjustbox}

\vspace{3ex}

With ``to 7em'' and ``X[c]''.
\vspace{1ex}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=7em}
%
\begin{tabu} to 7em {X[c]}
  \toprule
  \\
  Some reasonably, very much so, long text.
  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
%
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please mind that the text that seems to title each table is not actually a caption (trying not to confuse people with how a `\caption` would scale).

Comment: (i) use `adjustbox` for set tables width is not good idea, (ii) be watchful with use of `tabu`, it is buggy and not maintained.

Comment: Because of your comment, I posted a follow-up question, in case you'd be interested in providing more details.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401353/what-is-the-correct-way-to-scale-tables-to-fit-on-the-page

Answer (score 2):

The general rule really is never scale tables (whether `tabular` or `tabu` or anything else) however

In your first case with `c`, the tabu is the natural width of the text plus some `\tabcolsep` padding for the columns, then that is scaled back to 7em

In the second case the X column is essentially a full width paragraph, although as it's only one line, it looks shorter, so that full width text  is scaled to 7em so the text looks smaller.

In the third case the text is wrapped so that the natural width of the table is already 7em, so the scaling does nothing.

Comment: About the second case, you say the X column is a full-width paragraph; does this mean that the column has a width of \textwidth?

Comment: @dow yes I suspect so (has to be that way if you need the multipage version)