# What is the "correct" way to scale tables to fit on the page?

Tags: tables

This question is, in part, a follow-up to [How does one correctly scale tabu (not tabular)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401210/how-does-one-correctly-scale-tabu-not-tabular/401213#401213).

In general, I have been using `adjustbox` to scale wide tables to `\textwidth` as such:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  \\
  some very long text in the first column
  &
  some very long text in the second column
  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
```

What would the "correct" way of producing a good-looking, page-fitting table? Should I be using `tabular`, `tabular*`, or `tabu`? Should I be using `scalebox` or `adjustbox` as above, or in combination with something else?

Comment: You can use `tabularx` in the first place (there must be at least one `X` column). You can use a smaller font (`\small` or `\footnotesize` remain readable). Setting a smaller value of `\tabcolsep` (`6pt` × 2 by defaults) or `\arraycolsep` is interesting if there are many columns. In any case scaling the table is not recommended, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: there is no correct way to _scale_ tables as scaling should be avoided in almost all cases (you don't justify a paragraph by randomly scaling the lines giving inconsistent font sizes, and same should apply to text in tables)

Comment: you could use tabularx or there I'd just use tabular with fixed width columns p{3cm}p{4cm}  to allow line breaking

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand the inconsistent font reason; however, I have proof trees with long formulas that I need scaled---it's not pure text. Any recommendations on that?

Comment: make them small enough to fit, `\small` or `\tiny` or whatever. Or if you really consider the tree like an image that you scale to fit, use `\resizebox` (or `adjustbox` which is the same thing, but then it's not really a table at all and so the fact that the tree is implemented as a table internally or as tikz nodes or pstricks nodes or whatever is a minor implementation detail) this question (on the face of it) is asking about tables of text and there you can linebreak and choose font sizes so scaling is never needed.